# text wrapping issue in using ajax with select2

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-select2

I Think There Is A Problem With The Current Version,

In Use With Ajax If the Size of the Selected Data is Long as Text, Since the Current and Old Version, it does not go to the bottom line, it is seen as long,
I Think This Is A Problem

How Do I Detect?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZUsd.png)

Select2 Manually I add html option or if the text value of the option object is too long when I specify the data source, it aligns it to the cell, shifted to the bottom line after it is selected.

but when I fill it with select2 ajax, it directly overflows the selected data from the field.

How can I solve this error even if it’s a temporary solution?